# apollo-server - Conditionally exclude fields from selection set

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I have a situation where I would like to conditionally exclude a field from a query selection before I hit that query's resolver.

The use case being that my underlying API only exposes certain 'fields' based on the user's locale, and calls made to this API will throw errors if fields are requested that are not included of that locale.

I have tried an approach with directives,

```
type Person {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    medicare: String @locale(locales: ["AU"])
}

type query {
    person(id: Int!): Person
}
```

And using the `SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitFieldDefinition`, I override `field.resolve` for the `medicare` field to return null when the user locale doesn't match any of the locales defined on the directive.

However, when a client with a non `"AU"` locale executes the following

```
query {
  person(id: 111) {
      name
      medicareNumber
    }
  }
}
```

the field resolver for `medicare` is never called and the query resolver makes a request to the underlying API, appending the fields in the selection set (including the invalid `medicareNumber`) as query parameters. The API call returns an error object at this point.

I believe this makes sense as it seems that the directive resolver is on the `FieldDefinition` and would only be called when the `person` resolver returns a valid result.

Is there a way to achieve this sort of functionality, with or without directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I would caution against this kind of schema design. As a client, if I include a field in the selection set, I expect to see that field in the response -- removing the field from the selection set server-side goes against the spec and can cause unnecessary confusion (especially on a larger team or with a public API).

If you are examining the requested fields in order to determine the parameters to pass to your API call, then forcing a certain field to resolve to null won't do anything -- that field will still be included in the selection set. In fact, there's really no way to create a schema directive that will impact the selection set of a request.

The best approach here would be to 1) ensure any potentially-null fields are nullable in the schema and 2) explicitly filter the selection set wherever your selection-set-to-parameters logic is.

EDIT:

Schema directives won't show up as part of the schema object returned in the `info`, so they can't be used as flags. My suggestion would be to maintain a separate in-memory map. For example:

```
const fieldsByLocale = {
  US: {
    Person: ['name', 'medicareNumber'],  
  },
  AU: {
    Person: ['name'],
  },
}
```

then you could just access the appropriate list to filter with `fieldsByLocale[context.locale][info.returnType]`. This filtering logic is specific to your data source (in this case, the external API), so this is a bit cleaner than "polluting" the schema with information that pertains to the storage layer. If the APIs change, or you switch to a different source for this information altogether (like a database), you can update the resolvers without touching your type definitions. In fact, this way, the filtering logic can easily live inside a domain/service layer instead of your resolvers.

Comment: Right, thats a good point about confusing the client.  Would there be a way to easily flag fields on types (similar to directives) and have them flow through to the selection set? Currently, I have a somewhat hacky solution that traverse through the `info.selectionSet` and `info.schema` trees together to determine what fields from the selection set need to be filtered. 

Ideally, I would like to flag these fields at the schema level.

Comment: Forgot to mention that as a part of the `SchemaDirectiveVisitor.visitFieldDefinition` override for my directive, I'm mutating the `info` object by adding a `_locales` property on the field. Hence, why I am able to traverse the schema for flagged fields.
Thanks for the suggestion. Maintaining a map separate but fairly coupled to my schema seems tedious however. But it's given me some ideas to go off of.